# Keep RichTextBox scroll position to the middle as user types

Tags: winforms, scroll, textbox, richtextbox

I have a text control (RichTextBox) that is at the full height of the display when active. How do I make tht RTB to always be positioned **vertically** on the middle of the rich text box as the user types text?

Notice I said vertically because horizontally it should be at the character position where the user is typing, thus unchanged by the program.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but scrolling the control while the user is typing is awkward IMO. What do you want to do if user scrolls the content themselves?

Comment: The post does not say anything about scrolling while the user is typing, that would be absurd. It is about having its scroll POSITION in the middle so that the user keeps on typing on the middle of the RTB rather than it scrolling up every line the user adds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might work,

```
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
private const int SB_PAGEUP =2; // one page up

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam,
    IntPtr lParam);

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGEUP, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Hope helps,